# Installing/setting up Socket.IO on my server

Tags: javascript, ssh, node.js, websocket

Ok so I have read through the Socket.IO docs and I am still a little unsure of a couple of points:

The documentation says...

To run the demo, execute the following:

```
git clone git://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node.git socket.io
cd socket.io/example/
sudo node server.js
```

Now I don't know what this means at all! I think it may be command line interface. I of course have access to this on my localhost, but my online hosting package is a shared LAMP setup. Meaning I don't have access to the root command line (i think).

How do I actually setup socket.IO, is it impossible on my shared server package?

Appreciate any help...

W.

Comment: If any one could briefly run me though server command line basics I would love you. It's something I have never worked with!

Comment: Is node.js installed on your shared server? If not, you gotta jump that hurdle first :/

Comment: What is node.js for (in simple talk)?

Comment: BTW, this isn't really a stackoverflow.com question, more of a serverfault.com question.

Comment: "shared host" + node.js == "no go"

Comment: @Alfred Hello, this is years later but I've been looking online and thought that I've found a work around but I guess not. I have GoDaddy but have installed node.js and can work with it using PuTTY -- Problem is the socket variables don't seem to work properly and I'm unable to emit anything. I'm unable connect with my domain but am successful with localhost. Does this sound correct? I'm thinking GoDaddy has complete control and has blockades to IO sockets. -- If anyone can reply, that would be more than helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you aren't familiar with node.js or with basic command line usage then I would suggest that you use a hosted WebSockets solution like [pusherapp](http://pusherapp.com/). Trying to learn WebSockets, and Node.js, and the Linux command line all at once is going to lead to a lot of frustration. Take a look a pusherapp's [quick start guide](http://pusherapp.com/docs/quickstart), it's very easy to get started. You can have 5 simultaneous connections with a single application for free (I'm not affiliated with pusherapp).

**Updated** (with inline answers to questions):

If you are going to go the direction of running a Socket.IO application:

- You don't technically need git since you can download node.js and Socket.IO from their respective download links on github.
- You don't actually need a LAMP server to use Socket.IO. By default Socket.IO functions as a simple webserver in addition to a WebSockets server. If you want server side scripting then you might want Apache with mod_php, mod_python, etc.
- You don't technically need a dedicated server or even root access. You do need a system where you can have long running process. And if you want the service to start automatically when the system is rebooted, you probably want to add a startup file to /etc/init.d, /etc/rc.d which will require root access. Both node.js and Socket.IO can be installed and run from a normal home directory. If you want to run Socket.IO on a standard port like 80 or 443 then you will need to run it with root privilege.
- Node.JS scales quite well so Socket.IO will probably scale pretty well too.
- It's not a simple matter to get everything setup and working, but if your goal is a free solution for web serving+WebSockets then Socket.IO is probably is good route to at least explore if you are brave.

Comment: Thanks Kanaka, you seem to be an expert in this field! I am building a web application that requires a lot of 'live' features. Including chat and live feeds. I want it to be scalable to potentially 1000s of users. I think i really need to get my head round this socket.IO to be able to enjoy the cross browser socket features it offers. Am I right in thinking I must: 1. Upgrade to a virtual dedicated server. 2.Install git on the server. 3.Install node.js on the server. 4.Install socket.IO on the server; In order to get these features up and running?

Comment: Is there a simpler solution that has the scalability I require without having to install additional software onto my server? My original idea was to use Ajax short polling, but I now think that may be too resource intensive on my LAMP server.

Comment: Geeeze! I really appreciate your time to help me on this Kanaka. Although I do have ZERO experience in direct command line communication with my server, so a lot of the terms you use are foreign to me. I think I need to start from the very bottom and work my way up. What is a good learning resource to help me understand everything you are talking about?

Comment: It's definitely worthwhile learning all this but I do want to emphasize again that the areas you will need to learn are very large topics. To get started I would suggest searching for "best learn linux" and "best learn administration" on serverfault.com

Comment: 3 years later ---- any updates on ease of installation? I am running a Basic plan on Awardspace shared hosting - what are my chances of getting Socket.io running? The system I am setting up initially will run a one way connection, providing real time alerts to website customers that are being pushed from an admin page, the site is Joomla if that makes any differences.
I think http-long-polling be good for this but if I can get socket.io running that would be fantastic

Comment: RozzA: Awardspace is a traditional LAMP style hosting company. They don't appear to support long running server processes let alone node.js so I don't think you'll have much luck with Socket.IO. You should be able to do long-poll using one of the languages they support (perl, python, PHP, ruby). With long-poll you can get almost the same server to client latency as WebSockets (client to server latency is where WebSockets are a huge win).

Answer (score 2):

First you'll have to determine if your host supports SSH. Sometimes they don't by default on shared hosting, but if you ask they can turn it on. If it does you'll use some sort of SSH client to connect to it.  Putty for windows is the most common.  Then you'll use git, which is a source control program.  Which you'll probably have to install on your host, which may or may not be allowed.  If you can, this can be accomplished a number of ways, you'll want to read the git documentation, it will depend largely on what linux distribution you're running. CD is change directory, basic command line stuff.  sudo on the last line is telling the system to run the command as root, which it will ask you the password for, which you may not have access to on your host.  Sounds like you're gonna have an uphill battle on shared hosting.  You may want to opt for a VPS instead.

Comment: Oh you have SSH, misread that part, never mind.  You will need root though, so you'll have to contact your host about that.

Comment: Socket.IO doesn't need root any more even for the Flash fallback.

Answer (score 2):

If your shared host is a LAMP system with no command line access you're not going to get very far with Socket.IO.  The instructions you posted assume you have command line access and that you've installed the node.js runtime on your system.

If you really want to try this I recommend you get a VPS of your own (I use prgmr.com) to test it out.  For what it's worth I found the Socket.IO platform pretty nice to use once I got it up and running.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. So I believe I need to go through the following steps: 1. Upgrade to a vertiual dedicated server that gives me command line access.
2. Install git onto my server
3. Install node.js onto my server
4. Install socket.IO onto my server
5. Then I will have full access the to the socket.IO features?