# WebSockets with Node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have build a game using canvas and Javascript, and I would like to implement multiplayer functionality using WebSockets and Node.js

I'm completely new to Node, and I have managed to get a basic web server up and running with the following code:

```
var http = require("http");

console.log("Server started at port 8888");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

It all works, I get the response of "Hello World" when I navigate to to my server IP on port 8888. My question is, is this all I need to start using WebSockets with Node? I have heard people say I still need socket.io so that Node can use sockets, but I don't know if that's just a library to help me use sockets or if Node actually can't understand sockets.

The server basically has to keep a note of all players connected, their scores, their positions on the canvas, etc. A client will poll the server (using WebSockets) occasionally in order to get everyones positions and then update their canvas with the returned information. Would I need socket.io for this? Either way, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need socket-io because that's a library built on top of node js.
Socket io create's a "socket" so data can be transferred from a web app to server or vice versa. node js is just a javascript interface to your server.

there's information on how to setup socket-io on:

[Installing/setting up Socket.IO on my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410214/installing-setting-up-socket-io-on-my-server)

Answer (score 4):

Two weeks ago, I put on my blog tutorial on [Node.js & WebSocket - Simple chat tutorial](http://www.martinsikora.com/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial).
Basically, I took this [WebSocket module for Node.js](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node) and just extended this server template (no socket.io):

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    // process HTTP request. Since we're writing just WebSockets server
    // we don't have to implement anything.
});
server.listen(1337, function() { });

// create the server
wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

// WebSocket server
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

    // This is the most important callback for us, we'll handle
    // all messages from users here.
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            // process WebSocket message
        }
    });

    connection.on('close', function(connection) {
        // close user connection
    });
});
```

If you're developing multiplayer game you might be interested in talk [HTML5 Games with Rob Hawkes of Mozilla](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxylQ3W2iqE) (he describes his experience with developing multiplayer game based on WebSocket) and also article [Developing Multiplayer HTML5 Games with Node.js](http://smus.com/multiplayer-html5-games-with-node) (there's a paragraph about sharing JavaScripts among Node.js and frontend).