# Is it possible to start with socket.io on shared hosting and how

Tags: node.js, socket.io, hosting, devops, shared-hosting

I create some game and I need a `socket.io` server but I don't know is it possible to install it on shared hosting and how?

What do I need to install before socket.io **node.js** and **socket.io**?

How to start with socket.io

In documentation is so badly written. There is that I need to install socket.io with NPM command but where is that.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

it is somehow possible to some extent

> You don't technically need a dedicated server or even root access. You do need a system where you can have long running process. And if you want the service to start automatically when the system is rebooted, you probably want to add a startup file to /etc/init.d, /etc/rc.d which will require root access. Both node.js and Socket.IO can be installed and run from a normal home directory. If you want to run Socket.IO on a standard port like 80 or 443 then you will need to run it with root privilege.

view more : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410612/1061871

Answer (score 1):

You can't install something like node.js on shared hosting, because server assign equal resources for all clients and will be unfair as you use more than others, only if owner agree you. Besides if you want to work with websocket (I guess this is what you want) you can buy a dedicated IP on which you can open whichever port you want, but server must have installed 'php_sockets' extension. I recommand you to use [Ratchet](http://socketo.me), a nice websockets server implementation.